# Hive - only 1 subquery expression is supported

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 3 tables T1, T2, T3 with id column. I want to get the id's from T1 which are not in T2 and T3.

```
select id from T1 where id not in (select id from T2) and id not in (select id from T3).
```

But it throws error like Only 1 subquery expression is supported for a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join:

```
select T1.id 
  from T1 
       left join (select distinct id from T2) T2 on T2.id=T1.id
       left join (select distinct id from T3) T3 on T3.id=T1.id 
 where T2.id is NULL 
   and T3.id is NULL;
```

`distinct` is used in the subqueries to make sure joins will not multiply rows if the id is not unique in T2 and T3.

Comment: Again this has 2 sub queries. And do I need to use "T2.id and T3.id" or "T2.id  or T3.id"

Comment: @VanajaJayaraman This query should work fine.T2.id is NULL  AND T3.id is NULL